# How to check if any member of a needle array is in a haystack string via MySQL query

Tags: mysql

If I have a column of possible choices:

```
choices
-------
Coke
Pepsi
7-Up
Water
```

And I have a table of user feedback, how could I check to see if the feedback contains the list of choices?  Or more specific to my issue, I'm checking to see if the feedback contains the phrase: "I love {one of the choices}".  The list of choices can grow over time, but the feedback may have phrases such as "I love Milk" which I don't want to show up in the results.  Similarly, the feedback may say "I hate Water", which should not be in the results (unless, of course, they also say "I love Water" in the feedback).  So just doing a keyword match wouldn't work.

Is there is a function similar to `INSTR` and `IN`, where I could say, maybe:

```
   SELECT feedback_id FROM feedback where 
          INSET(feedback_note, SELECT CONCAT("I Love ", choices) FROM choice_list)
```

### Update

I didn't know about the `ANY` operator worked until after asking, but my attempt to use it isn't working.  I tried:

```
 SELECT feedback_id, feedback_note FROM feedback 
     having feedback_note LIKE ANY 
         (SELECT distinct CONCAT("I love ", choices, "%") from choice_list);
```

This is just not allowed, I learned, so I thought I'd at least see if would work for a one line "I love Pepsi" so I did:

```
 SELECT feedback_id, feedback_note FROM feedback 
     having feedback_note = ANY 
         (SELECT distinct CONCAT("I love ", choices, "%") from choice_list);
```

And after a minute or so, the query was still running (I executed it). So is there some way to use `LIKE` and `ANY` together, maybe not directly?

Comment: I can't hear the expression "needle array" without thinking of the Hellraiser movies. *shudder*

Comment: Regex on a varchar field might work but it's _horrifically_ slow.

Comment: Even if I did Regex, how would I get the choice list into the expression?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the LIKE condition with wildcards.

For, example if you have the following table schema:
[choices]
id | text
1  | Coke
2  | Pepsi

[feedback]
id | note
1  | I love Pepsi.
2  | I really like Coke
3  | This comment has nothing to do with anything

In PostgreSQL you could do something like:

```
SELECT feedback.id
FROM feedback, choices
WHERE choices.text in (SELECT text FROM choices)
AND feedback.note LIKE '%' || text || '%'
```

or

```
SELECT feedback.id
FROM feedback 
INNER JOIN choices ON feedback.note LIKE '%' || choices.text || '%'
```

(the second one is faster)

% is the wildcard operator, the LIKE condition will match anything that has choice between any other characters.

I have no way to test this code right now, but something similar should work in PostgreSQL.

ps: || is the string concatenation operator in PostgreSQL, beware that string concatenation varies between rdbms.
ps2: you can also use ILIKE instead of LIKE if you want it to be case insensitive

Comment: Thanks for the PS. I was totally lost for a second.

Comment: Your solution doesn't quite fit, because I don't have a `choice` column on the row. That's the whole issue. I need to see if any of the choices show up anywhere in the string.

Comment: edited my answer, tested the code and it works well, hope it helps now

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
SELECT feedback_id, feedback_note 
FROM feedback 
 WHERE 
   SUBSTRING(feedback_note,1,7) = "I Love " and
   SUBSTRING(feedback_note FROM 8) in
     (SELECT choices from choice_list)
```

or:

```
SELECT feedback_id, feedback_note 
FROM feedback 
 WHERE 
   SUBSTRING(feedback_note,1,7) = "I Love " and
   exists 
     (SELECT 1 from choice_list
      where choices = SUBSTRING(feedback_note FROM 8)
     )
```

Comment: remember to create a index on choice_list (choices) if this table has lot of rows.